# Integrating facebook login with Angular

Tags: angular, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to find a resource to integrate facebook login into my Angular project  , but I am not successful yet. Can I get a useful resource to integrate facebook login into my project

Comment: Can you please provide more information. What have you tried so far. What version of Angular are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular (not AngularJS) maybe [this post will help you](https://samkirkiles.svbtle.com/angular-4-facebook-login-integration) like it did help me too.